# Setting alignment of JComponents

Tags: java, swing, alignment, border-layout

I would want a sequential way of representing the components in my GUI using Java Swing. I am currently using BorderLayout with a BOX in the center.

I would want the JFileChooser at the left, JButtons in the center and JList at the right side of the verticalFrame.
[image: Alignment]

The above figure shows my current alignment of the components.

It would be really helpful for me if anbody could please tell me how to align the components according to our needs.

According to m figure, JList is at the top, followed b checkbox and then JFileChooser followed by three buttons.

Comment: Generally, the solution is multiple JPanels using one or more GridBagLayouts.

Comment: So should i assign each panel a component and then proceed or..?

Comment: Or should I change my current layout to GridBagLayout ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  I think you've already been offered the best solution by mKorbel.  If that is not the case for your use, perhaps the SSCCE will explain why that is.

Comment: Atlast, I tried using GridBagLayout which more or less solved my purpose. Hence, I am fixing my alignments currently.

Answer (score 3):

my answer isn't... , but should be most nicer for `BorderLayout`

- `JList` to the `EAST` (or `WEST`) area
- `JFileChooser` to the CENTER area
- `JPanel` with `JButtons` to the `SOUTH` (or `NORTH`) area

maybe use `GridBagLayout` (very complicated `LayoutManager`)

easy for use is `MigLayout`

EDIT

```
I am unable to add JList to EAST or WEST since the frame is not getting 
extended more than the JFileChooser.
```

Q: you are not able or is there some requirent(e) or limitation(s)

A: whats wrong with my original idea

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BorderLayoutWithJComponents {

    public BorderLayoutWithJComponents() {
        String[] subItems1 = {"Red", "Blue", "Green", "Circle", "Square",
        "Triangle", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};
        JList list = new JList(subItems1);
        JFileChooser myFileChooser= new JFileChooser();
        JButton one = new JButton("One");
        JButton two = new JButton("Two");
        JButton three = new JButton("Three");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(one);
        panel.add( two);
        panel.add(three);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("LayoutTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(list, BorderLayout.WEST);
        f.add(myFileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
              new  BorderLayoutWithJComponents();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for our suggestion.! I will try this out.

Comment: I am unable to add JList to EAST or WEST since the frame is not getting extended more than the JFileChooser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this idea.! My idea is to add the JList as well as the buttons(panel) to EAST, which means JFileChooser should be the first and then followed by the rest. Is it possible that both would come to EAST?

Comment: Actually what I think is in Borderlayout, it cannot be sequentially aligned but this can only align-NORTH,SOUTH,EAST,WEST side, just like this example http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/WhatistheBorderLayout.htm

Comment: But may be I can try MIGLayout